# How to properly format the output Get-ItemProperty of multiple files?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to get some detailed info about DLL files, using `Get-ItemProperty`.
However I am not able to format the resulting output in a nice way.

This is what I got:

```
$zz = (ls C:\Windows\System32\*.dll).FullName

foreach ($f in $zz){
    Get-ItemProperty -Path $f |Select -ExpandProperty VersionInfo |select ProductVersionRaw, OriginalFilename, FileDescription | ft -HideTableHeaders
}

# ...
# 10.0.19041.867    vidreszr.dll     Windows Media Resizer
```

The result is ugly as it:

- is not aligned,
- have 2 newlines between each item,
- are missing some filenames

**Q: How can I format the resulting table properly?**

---

**UPDATE:**

I made some progress with:

```
& { foreach ($f in $zz){ Get-ItemProperty -Path $f |Select -ExpandProperty VersionInfo |select ProductVersionRaw, OriginalFilename, FileDescription } } | ft
```

But still missing filename info on some files.

---

**SOLUTION:**

Thanks @n0rd's solution and some searching, I managed to get what I want:

```
$zz = (ls C:\Windows\System32\*.dll).FullName

& { foreach ($f in $zz){ Get-ItemProperty -Path $f |Select Name, @{Name="CreationTime";Expression= {"{0:yyyy}-{0:MM}-{0:dd}" -f ([DateTime]$_.CreationTime)}} -ExpandProperty VersionInfo |select ProductVersionRaw, CreationTime, Name, FileDescription } } | sort -Property Name | ft
```

This:

- Changes the *CreationTime* format to: `yyyy-MM-dd`
- Sorts on the *real* filename (`Name`)
- To select only a specific *ProductVersionRaw*, insert:
  `| ?{ $_.ProductVersionRaw -eq "10.0.19041.nnnn" }` before `| ft`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it in a single command, there is no need to save the list and iterate over it:

```
Get-ChildItem c:\windows\system32\*.dll | Get-ItemProperty | ForEach-Object {$_.VersionInfo} | Select-Object -Property ProductVersionRaw,OriginalFilename,FileDescription
```

`Get-ItemProperty` can accept input from a pipe.

Also, using `ForEach-Object` over `Select-Object -ExpandProperty` is how I'd usually do it, but both work fine.

Alternatively, you could save the output of your commands up to `ft` call into a list, then feed that whole list into `ft` (so it has full context for formatting).

Comment: I wasn't able to pipe it the way you do, because the objects appear at different levels. Namely `Name` appears in the first level. Please see my solution if it is possible to make a shorter pipe version of that.